# Subsequent calls to Geocode() script error

Tags: geocoding, gmlib

I need to resolve a list of coords to geocode, but after call GMGeoCode1.Geocode() function for a while, it returns error executing script line 243, char 21, length is null or not an object.

I have isolated that function so I am able to get some control and wait for the response - GMGeoCode1AfterGetData procedure. I cannot see if it´s because of one of the coords to invalid and raises that exception.

Is there any clever way to get in batch mode? If I need to loop how could I proceed?

Regards!

Comment: I just forgot to say, the problem itself is because of the very quick subsequent query to the function, so I would need to know how to wait it before a new request... my flow control above is not working

Comment: You need to wait 1sec between every query ;-)